# incompatible type of double array and properties string.split()

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input="jack=susan,kathy,bryan;david=stephen,jack;murphy=bruce,simon,mary";
    String[][] family = new String[50][50];

    //assign family and children to data by ;
    StringTokenizer p = new StringTokenizer (input,";");
    int no_of_family = input.replaceAll("[^;]","").length();
    no_of_family++;
    System.out.println("family= "+no_of_family);
    String[] data = new String[no_of_family];
    int i=0;
    while(p.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        data[i] = p.nextToken();
        i++;
    }

    for (int j=0;j<no_of_family;j++)
    {
        family[j][0] = data[j].split("=")[0];
                    //assign child to data by commas
        StringTokenizer v = new StringTokenizer (data[j],",");
        int no_of_child = data[j].replaceAll("[^,]","").length();
        no_of_child++;

        System.out.println("data from input = "+data[j]);
        for (int k=1;k<=no_of_child;k++)
        {

            family[j][k]= data[j].split("=")[1].split(",");
            System.out.println(family[j][k]);
        }

    }

}
```

i have a list of family in input string and i seperate into a family and i wanna do it in double array family[i][j].

my goal is:

```
family[0][0]=1st father's name
family[0][1]=1st child name
family[0][2]=2nd child name and so on...

family[0][0]=jack
family[0][1]=susan
family[0][2]=kathy
family[0][3]=bryan
family[1][0]=david
family[1][1]=stephen
family[1][2]=jack
family[2][0]=murphy
family[2][1]=bruce
family[2][2]=simon
family[2][3]=mary
```

but i got the error as title: in compatible types
found:java.lang.String[]
required:java.lang.String
family[j][k]= data[j].split("=")[1].split(",");

what can i do?i need help

nyone know how to use StringTokenizer for this input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to understand why you can't just use split for your nested operation as well.

For example, something like this should work just fine

```
for (int j=0;j<no_of_family;j++)
{
    String[] familySplit = data[j].split("=");

    family[j][0] = familySplit[0];

    String[] childrenSplit = familySplit[1].split(",");
    for (int k=0;k<childrenSplit.length;k++)
    {

        family[j][k+1]= childrenSplit[k];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign an array of strings to a string. Maybe this will make it more clear?

```
String[] array = data.split("=")[1].split(",");
```

Now, if you want the first element of that array you can then do:

```
family[j][k] = array[0];
```

Comment: it will clean with error but the data i will have will always the 1st data and when i put family[j][k]=array[k] i got this message: exception in thread.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException...

Comment: So...you need to make sure you are accessing an array within its bounds. In your code you assume an index value of `1` for your first split, and I assumed an index of `0` in my example.

Answer (score 1):

I always avoid to use arrays directly. They are hard to manipulate versus dynamic list. I implemented the solution using a Map of parent to a list of childrens `Map<String, List<String>>` (read `Map<Parent, List<Children>>`).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "jack=susan,kathy,bryan;david=stephen,jack;murphy=bruce,simon,mary";

        Map<String, List<String>> parents = new Hashtable<String, List<String>>();
        for ( String family : input.split(";")) {
            final String parent = family.split("=")[0];
            final String allChildrens = family.split("=")[1];

            List<String> childrens = new Vector<String>();
            for (String children : allChildrens.split(",")) {
                childrens.add(children);
            }
            parents.put(parent, childrens);
        }

        System.out.println(parents);
    }
```

The output is this:

```
{jack=[susan, kathy, bryan], murphy=[bruce, simon, mary], david=[stephen, jack]}
```

With this method you can directory access to a parent using the map:

```
System.out.println(parents.get("jack"));
```

and this output:

```
[susan, kathy, bryan]
```